# Move Jquery down

Tags: jquery, position

I've added some script to my site: http://cargocollective.com/btatest

However, I'd love to move it down 40px.

I've tried to wrap it in a div, but to no avail.

Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // The social div 
    var $socialDiv,
        // The social div's height 
        socialDivHeight = 500,
        currentSocialDivHeight = socialDivHeight;


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $socialDiv = $('.social');
        $socialDiv.css({
            'background-image': 'url(http://fearthegrizzly.com/productions/theacrobat/web3.jpg)',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
            'background-attachment': 'fixed',
            'background-size' : '110% 100%',
            'height' : socialDivHeight + 'px',
            'margin-left' : '-50%',
            'margin-right' : '-50%',

        });
    });


    $(window).scroll(function() { 
        //Get scroll position of window 
        var windowScroll = $(this).scrollTop(); 

        var newSocialDivHeight = Math.max(0, socialDivHeight - windowScroll);

        if (Math.abs(newSocialDivHeight - currentSocialDivHeight) < 1)
            return;

        $socialDiv.css({
            'opacity' : 1 - windowScroll / 400
        });

        currentSocialDivHeight = newSocialDivHeight;
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Michael

Comment: You've tried to wrap *what* in a `div`? And you'd like to move *what* down the page?

Comment: You want to move your script by 40px?  If you mean some actual element, like a `div`, you can do `margin-top: 40px` or `position: relative; top: 40px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-top` property to your Class Name **.social** CSS settings like this:

```
$socialDiv.css({
            'background-image': 'url(http://fearthegrizzly.com/productions/theacrobat/web3.jpg)',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
            'background-attachment': 'fixed',
            'background-size' : '110% 100%',
            'height' : socialDivHeight + 'px',
            'margin-left' : '-50%',
            'margin-right' : '-50%',
            'margin-top': '40px'
        });
```